# extend parent and children nested selectors in less

Tags: less

#### Background:

I'm attempting to use semantic markup while creating a new project using Bootstrap 3 as the CSS framework and I'm primarily using less's extend feature to apply the bootstrap styles. However, when I attempt to extend nested selectors, less is not creating the CSS output I am expecting.

Here is a simplistic example of the issue I'm running into:

#### HTML Markup:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

#### LESS

```
.parent-class{
    parentProperty: value;
    .child-class { parentChildProperty: value; }
}

.child-class {
    childProperty:value;
    & > li{ childLiProperty:value; }
}

nav{
    &:extend(.parent-class all);
    ul{
        &:extend(.child-class all);
    }
}
```

#### Actual CSS Output:

```
.parent-class,
nav {
  parentProperty: value;
}
.parent-class .child-class,
nav .child-class,
.parent-class nav ul {
  parentChildProperty: value;
}
.child-class,
nav ul {
  childProperty: value;
}
.child-class > li,
nav ul > li {
  childLiProperty: value;
}
```

### Issues

The issue with the output is that the parentChildProperty will not be applied to the ul element because the selector **nav ul** is not generated. My initial expectation was for less to infer this selector based on the nesting. However, that does not appear to work.

Additionally, the undesired selector of **.parent-class nav ul** is being generated. I realize this is because of the use of the all keyword when extending **ul** with **.child-class**. However, without the all keyword childLiProperty would not be applied correctly. Ideally, my preferred output would look like the example below.

### Desired Output

```
.parent-class,
nav {
  parentProperty: value;
}
.parent-class .child-class,
nav ul {
  parentChildProperty: value;
}
.child-class,
nav ul {
  childProperty: value;
}
.child-class > li,
nav ul > li {
  childLiProperty: value;
}
```

Is there any way to enable the expected behavior with less, or is there a better way to structure the less styles to achieve the goal of using semantic html with bootstrap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with `parentChildProperty` not being applied to the `ul` element can be fixed by also extending `.parent-class .child-class` in the `ul` styles

This will not resolve all the issues. It will still leave many unnecessary selectors in the generated CSS, but it will generate the required CSS to allow the page to display correctly.

#### Updated less:

```
.parent-class{
    parentProperty: value;
    .child-class { parentChildProperty: value; }
}

.child-class {
    childProperty:value;
    & > li{ childLiProperty:value; }
}

nav{
    &:extend(.parent-class all);
    ul{
        &:extend(.child-class all);
        &:extend(.parent-class .child-class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this is just how `extend` and `extend all` work in Less (both have very poor notion of own Less nesting). Btw., you can slightly improve your CSS result with something like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/9d78058a086bc48bb914), but no more than that. In particular, the purpose of `all` is not to "extend" any nested stuff but actually extend *all* selectors with matched elements in, so unless you're ready to point to [all four selectors explicitly](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/77d6a0607db5f464f85b) w/o `all` you'll get that unnecessary stuff.

Comment: Also, speaking of using Bootstrap sources as a skeleton for your own semantic CSS, see [this collection](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/cefc873a78fa12924462) of critic comments. (And your example is a nice one to become #5 there).

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thanks for the suggestion on cleaning up the syntax a little. Your version looks a bit cleaner. Overall, I think this is a viable solution. However, adding the additional extend is still not as clean as I would hope, mainly in regards to the extraneous selectors that get add in the generated CSS and in terms of maintainability moving forward. While this example is pretty small, on a full site there would probably be many cases where "duplicate" extend selectors would need to be included

Comment: @seven-phases-max I see what you mean that using the explicit selectors and eliminating `all` would reduce the extraneous selectors from the CSS. However, with Bootstrap there would be many more than 4 selectors that need to be extended. It would be nice if there was a way that less could figure out the appropriate selectors to extend based on the nesting, but that may just be wishful thinking on my part. I certainly haven't given much thought to use cases other than my own, or any edge cases that might crop up.

Comment: Almost implemented [`extend deep`](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2101) will probably slightly improve the situation. But only partially, since (as already mentioned in the links above) it's nearly impossible to design a "selector/ruleset inheriting feature" that can turn a "non-semantic CSS theming framework" into a "semantic CSS construction kit library".